# Why can I not add to my array list

Tags: java, arraylist

When I go to run the code, the only thing that is printed is [].  I have copied the code below.

```
 java.util.ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new  java.util.ArrayList();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < list2.size() ; i++) {
            list2.add(input.nextInt());
        }
        System.out.println(list2);

}
```

Comment: What do you think `list2.size()` does?

Comment: its supposed to go until the end of the list

Comment: What is the end of the list in this case?

Comment: and what is the end of the list in this case?

Comment: the size of the list isn't specified because its an arraylist.  It should just be able to accept as many numbers as I want

Comment: It will accept as many numbers as you want. But at the time of running the for loop for first time it will check for the size of arraylist at that time which is 0. So it won't execute at all. That's what everyone is trying to suggest

Comment: It is a dynamic list however the size of the list is based on the CURRENT number of elements which in this case is 0.

Comment: why dont you use other method for looping? like "while"?

Answer (score 3):

That *loop* will not execute, as the list is empty at the beginning of the code. If there was an element in that list, the loop would keep on adding elements forever.

```
        import  java.util.ArrayList;

        ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        list2.add(1); //sample value

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 0; i < list2.size() ; i++) {
            list2.add(input.nextInt());
        }

        System.out.println(list2);
```

Comment: Why did you delete the comment that when there's an element in the list, the for loop would run for ever? That was correct, and a good point. You should reinstate it.

Comment: And when will the loop end?

Answer (score 2):

As it does not have any elements yet.

```
list2.size()
```

returns 0

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are never entering the loop because the size of the list is `0` as is `i`. You would first need to add something to the list to make the for loop execute.